# xslt error: Extra illegal tokens: 'eq', ''center'' when transforming my xml via xsl/xslt via xalan/java

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

i am trying to transform my xml via java/xalan (2.7.1) with org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process class

I am getting "Extra illegal tokens" and not sure of the work around

i basically want to pass in a parameter to a Template and then use that parameter as a attribute of a `<xsl:when test="$textAlign eq 'center'">`

if i pass a `'center'` param into TableCell template, I would want to create a table cell that has it's text centered, and of course, `'left'` would get it's contents left justified.

the error message is complaining about the `'center'`

the quotes around center trip it up and seems like it should be okay.

here are a few snippets (sample xml and xsl)

```
    <ingredients>         
          <ingredient>
                <quantity>1 1/2</quantity>
                <foodstuff>flour</foodstuff>
          </ingredient>
    </ingredients>
```

and here is a sample xsl

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="ingredients">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ingredient"/>
</xsl:template>
.
<xsl:template match="ingredient">
  <xsl:call-template name="TableCell">
        <xsl:with-param name="cellValue" select="quantity" />
        <xsl:with-param name="textAlign" select="'center'" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
.
<xsl:template name="TableCell">
  <xsl:param name="cellValue" />
  <xsl:param name="textAlign" />
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$textAlign eq 'center'">
      <td align='center'>
        <xsl:value-of select="$cellValue"/>
      </td>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

maybe there is another way to do this? I thought it was pretty simple but i guess I just not versed enough on xsl

I am using xalan 2.7.1 for my xsl engine

```
org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN test.xml -XSL test.xsl -OUT out.html
```

thanks everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eq` is an operator introduced in XPath and XSLT 2.0, you are using Xalan which only supports XPath and XSLT 1.0 so use the `=` operator instead.
Or move from Xalan to Saxon 9 (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), that processor supports XSLT 2.0.

Comment: dang it, i should have noticed that, i am actually using FOP to convert to PDF, so as much as i would like to use the latest xslt/xpath 2.0, i think it may be more work than just swapping jars. thanks for your reply